# Java queue linkedlist

Tags: java, c, linked-list, queue

I'm trying to convert the following into java. I made a student class and join StudentNode and Queue by using `LinkedList<Student> studentList.`
How do I do the following 4 things in java?

```
Student *studentPtr;
StudentNode *p;
1. p.student = studentPtr;
2. p.next = null;

Queue readyQueue;
3. readyQueue.head
4. readyQueue.tail

typedef struct{
   int age;


}Student;
struct my_struct
    {
      Student student;
      struct my_struct* next;
    }StudentNode;


struct my_list
{
  struct my_struct* head;
  struct my_struct* tail;
}Queue;
```

Can anyone please help me to convert the following function to java method?

```
StudentNode *makeStudentNode(Student *stPtr)
{
    StudentNode *p = (StudentNode *)malloc(sizeof(StudentNode));

   p->student = stPtr;
   p->next = NULL;
   return p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`java.util.LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is already available in library, you may use it.

```
List<student> studList = new LinkedList<student>(); 
Student st = new Student();
st.setName("...");
studList.add(st);
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I know use LinkedList, but I don't know how to do the above 4 things

Comment: p.student = studentPtr; What will this be look like?

Comment: I have updated the code, there is no pointer in java

Comment: Thanks. So the head and tail is equalivent getFirst and getLast right?How to access the next using LinkedList?

Comment: yes those are available, LinkedList implements `Deque<E>, List<E> and Queue<E>` interface. [Find more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

Comment: StudentNode *makeStudentNode(Student *stPtr)
{
    StudentNode *p = (StudentNode *)malloc(sizeof(StudentNode));

   p->student = stPtr;
   p->next = NULL;
   return p;
}How to convert this function to java method?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Student {
   int age;
}
```

and instead a queue

```
List<Student> studentList;
```

in code you will initialize the by:

```
studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

or if you prefer to be nearer to the queue:

```
studentList = new LinkedList<Student>();
```

adding students:

```
studentList.add(new Student(23));
studentList.add(new Student(19));
```

and removeing first element

```
studenList.remove(0);
```

if theList was defined as LinkedList:

```
LinkedList<Student> studentList;
```

then you could remove the head with

```
studentList.remove();
```

You can iterate through all students:

```
for (Student student: studentList) {
   System.out.println(student.age);
}
```

Or using an Iterator:

```
 for (Iterator<Student> iterator = studentList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
     Student student = iterator.next();
     System.out.println(student.age);
 }
```

Comment: How to access the next ?